# How to only allow certain words in .htaccess regex?

Tags: regex, .htaccess

For example, I can write the following `.htaccess` rule at the base directory of my domain (`/`):

```
RewriteRule ^something/[bd]on$ foo.php [L]
```

Which would match the following URLs, providing my domain is `www.example.com`:

```
http://www.example.com/something/bon
http://www.example.com/something/don
```

right? But how would I put words in there to match? For example, `apple` and `cheese`, so that it only matches:

```
http://www.example.com/something/apple
http://www.example.com/something/cheese
```

Note that I have around 40 different possibilities after `something/`, so please provide me with an `.htaccess` rule which can accommodate that.

Comment: Did you try `^something/(apple|cheese)$`?

Comment: @inhan nope, didn't try that. If you'd put that as an answer, I'd accept it.

Comment: I thought you had already tried it without success. Just posted this as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

40 words sounds long but AFAIK, the only way to make a Regex pattern match a set of options is to explicitly write them in parantheses, separated by the pipe `|` character.

So I think `RewriteRule ^something/(word1|word2|word3)$ foo.php [L]` should work for you.

**EDIT:**

I forgot to mention. To shorten the list you can use character groups/ranges and conditions for the words (such as `colou?r` or `gr[ae]y`) but that will make it look confusing later when you need to edit it.